# Actors (scala/akka): is it implied that the receive method will be accessed in a threadsafe manner?

Tags: scala, thread-safety, akka, actor

I assume that the messages will be received and processed in a threadsafe manner. However, I have been reading (some) akka/scala docs but I didn't encounter the keyword 'threadsafe' yet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is probably because the actor model assumes that each actor instance processes its own mailbox sequentially. That means it should never happen, that two or more concurrent threads execute single actor instance's code. Technically you could create a method in an actor's class (because it is still an object) and call it from multiple threads concurrently, but this would be a major departure from the actor's usage rules and you would do it "at your own risk", because then you would lose all thread-safety guarantees of that model.

This is also one of the reasons, why Akka introduced a concept of [ActorRef](http://akka.io/api/1.0/akka-actor/akka/actor/ActorRef.html) - a handle, that lets you communicate with the actor through message passing, but not by calling its methods directly.

Comment: Thanks Przemek. That explains.

Answer (score 5):

I think we have it pretty well documented: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/general/jmm.html

Comment: I read that document multiple times. I am a JVM newbie; in my understanding, a 'happens before' only substantiates 'visibility'. We can still have issues due to multiple threads in critical section.

Comment: Akka safeguards against executing messages for the same actor at the same time by only ever allowing the mailbox to be scheduled for execution once. (either it's scheduled for execution or it's not). By making the Mailbox Runnable not only do we avoid allocating new runnables, but we also can, via a simple CAS operation, ensure that a mailbox is only ever scheduled for execution once, which means no extra book-keeping required to make sure that 2 threads do not process the same mailbox at the same time.

Comment: Awesome explanation. This will surely help me in further reading. One question though, how could I have deduced the 'mutually exclusive processing' of mailbox from http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/general/jmm.html?

Comment: Akka Actors wouldn't be actors if they allowed multiple execution. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Actors are 'Treadsafe'. The Actor System (AKKA), provides each actor with its own 'light-weight thread'. Meaning that this is not a tread, but the AKKA system will give the impression that an Actor is always running in it's own thread to the developer. This means that any operations performed as a result of acting on a message are, for all purposes, thread safe.

However, you should not undermine AKKA by using mutable messages or public state. If you develop you actors to be stand alone units of functionality, then they will be threadsafe.

See also:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/actors.html#State

and
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/jmm.html for a more indepth study of the AKKA memory model and how it manages 'tread' issues.